# Removing HTML tags from a column in an excel file using java

Tags: java, html, excel, loops, tableau-api

I am using a java code to remove HTML tags from a text file. But my requirement is that, I want to access an excel file using java, and remove the HTML tags from each row of a particular column. How can I access an excel file using javascript and how to integrate my java code(removing HTML tags) into that...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class Html2TextWithRegExp {

    private Html2TextWithRegExp() {}

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("java-new.txt"));
        String line;
        while ( (line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        String nohtml = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
        System.out.println(nohtml);
        try(  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( "nohtml.txt" )){
            out.println( nohtml );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). Then you can do this:

```
String noHTML = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString()).text();
```

Don't use regexes; HTML is not a regular language and you're unlikely to be able to deal with all the special cases that are bound to crop up.

I recently used this very method to clean up a bunch of forum posts that I was using for a machine-learning task, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your response @vivin. That's fine. But my requirement is to loop through each cell of a particular column in excel sheet. Can someone help me with that...

Comment: @ManinderDornala Sorry; I misunderstood your question. You can take a look at [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).